# 'angular-backtop' back to top button not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I am trying to implement a back to top button as easily as possibly in my angular app.

I found the [angular-backtop](https://github.com/padsbanger/angular-backtop) directive and it seems perfect but I can't get it to work.

I have `angular-backtop.js` and `angular-backtop.css` included in my index file and `'angular-backtop'` included as a dependency in my main module.

In the `angular-backtop.js` the use of scope is present (without $) and I know there is a bug where scope [doesn't work](https://github.com/angular/router/issues/313) with the new angular router which I am using. Is this why the angular backtop isn't working?

It seems like this isn't correlated but I'm not sure why else this wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you provide link to Codepen or JSBin or Plunkr with your code ??

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is inject that directive anywhere you want into your html file as 
`<back-top></back-top>`